# Perforce(P4) slow on ubuntu

Tags: perforce, ubuntu-16.04

I installed p4 on ubuntu 16.04 and configured it as instructed. Everything is fine, other computers(windows) could connect to the server but the problem is it takes a long time to respond.

An example would of this is when I run on the server(ubuntu) or client(windows):

```
p4 -p 192.168.1.150:1666 info
```

it takes 10 secs to return the info

Answer (score 0):

Probably a network problem, since `p4 info` does very little actual work.  Have you done all the troubleshooting steps from this article already?

http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/3126

Comment: I'll try to check out the article. But if it's is a network issue, why does it take the same amount of time to respond when I run p4 info on the **server**?

Comment: Same interface.  Try `p4 -p localhost:1666` and see if it's different.

Answer (score 0):

Are all operations slow, or just p4 info? If it's just the info command it may be your DNS. Info does a DNS lookup of the Perforce server and it takes a while to time out if there's no DNS server.